# ExecutionContext and Thread safety on Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I read few articles about that but Iam not sure about my case.

I am using ExecutionContext in order to pass params from Tasklet to Step

I wanna make sure that if I am executing same job instances in parallel using the same steps I wont have concurrency side-effects.

Thats my job:

```
 @Bean
    public Job processFileJob() throws Exception {
        return this.jobs.get("processFileJob").start(downloadFileStep()).next(processSnidFileStep()).build();

    }

  public Step downloadFileStep() {
        return this.steps.get("downloadFileTaskletStep").tasklet(downloadFileTasklet()).listener(executionContextPromotionListener()).build();
    }
```

I am passing param from downloadFileStep to processSnidFileStep this way:

```
public class DownloadFileTasklet implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {
..
      private void downloadFileFromExtractTool(ChunkContext chunkContext, 
    ..
            stepContext.put("totalRecords", totalRecords);
    ..
}
```

and retrieve the param onto my step this way:

```
 @Bean
    @Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public ItemProcessor<MyDTO, MyDTO> processor(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext[totalRecords]}") int totalRecords
                                                            ) {
        return new PushItemProcessor(totalRecords);
    }
```

Now I can see that param successfully inside processor step.

But what if I execute the whole job in parallel having different values for different jobs? any concurrent side effects?

Thank you.
ray.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "execute the whole job in parallel"? In Spring Batch each job instance has its own JobExecution, so there should be no side effects by starting n jobinstances

Comment: sorry for being unclear. I meant if I execute in parallel many instances of the same job..

Comment: @rayman i have a similar use case that multiple instances of same job are running. but my executionContext is getting mixed or is available to all the instances of the same job. were you able to find the solution for this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the spring batch reference we can see that one of the usages is "Concurrent batch processing: parallel processing of a job"

As already answered in the comments the job instance has it's own job execution, which has it's own context, so the spring batch design is assume thread safety for execution context, if you follow the design of course.

Here is a link to Spring batch reference guide, it's not that big actually

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/spring-batch-intro.html#springBatchUsageScenarios